# tkinter - Draw and view multiple stages of networkx graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, networkx

I am using Ford-Fulkerson algorithm to find the maximum flow of a graph and also visualize the process. I want to draw the graph at every stage while the flow changes.

I've drawn every stage, but they are stacking up one on another, I want to save the plots and change them using matplotlib's `NavigationToolbar2Tk` arrows.

```py
from tkinter import *
import networkx as nx
from pandas import DataFrame
from digraph import ford_fulkerson
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

window = Tk()
window.title("Graphs")

graph = nx.DiGraph()
graph.add_nodes_from('ABCDEFGH')
graph.add_edges_from([
    ('A', 'B', {'capacity': 4, 'flow': 0}),
    ('A', 'C', {'capacity': 5, 'flow': 0}),
    ('A', 'D', {'capacity': 7, 'flow': 0}),
    ('B', 'E', {'capacity': 7, 'flow': 0}),
    ('C', 'E', {'capacity': 6, 'flow': 0}),
    ('C', 'F', {'capacity': 4, 'flow': 0}),
    ('C', 'G', {'capacity': 1, 'flow': 0}),
    ('D', 'F', {'capacity': 8, 'flow': 0}),
    ('D', 'G', {'capacity': 1, 'flow': 0}),
    ('E', 'H', {'capacity': 7, 'flow': 0}),
    ('F', 'H', {'capacity': 6, 'flow': 0}),
    ('G', 'H', {'capacity': 4, 'flow': 0}),

])

layout = {
    'A': [0, 1], 'B': [1, 2], 'C': [1, 1], 'D': [1, 0],
    'E': [2, 2], 'F': [2, 1], 'G': [2, 0], 'H': [3, 1],
}

def draw_graph():
    # create first place for plot
    ax1 = f.add_subplot(211)
    nx.draw_networkx_nodes(graph, layout, node_color='steelblue', node_size=600, ax = ax1)
    nx.draw_networkx_edges(graph, layout, edge_color='gray', ax = ax1)
    nx.draw_networkx_labels(graph, layout, font_color='white', ax = ax1)

    for u, v, e in graph.edges(data=True):
        label = '{}/{}'.format(e['flow'], e['capacity'])
        color = 'green' if e['flow'] < e['capacity'] else 'red'
        x = layout[u][0] * .6 + layout[v][0] * .4
        y = layout[u][1] * .6 + layout[v][1] * .4
        ax1.text(x, y, label, size=16, color=color, horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center')

    right_frame.draw()

def flow_debug(graph, path, reserve, flow):
    print('flow increased by', reserve,
          'at path', path,
          '; current flow', flow)
    draw_graph()

def plot_max_flow():
    ford_fulkerson(graph, 'A', 'H', flow_debug)


top_left_frame = Frame(window)
top_left_frame.pack(side = LEFT)

VertexData = Entry(top_left_frame)
VertexData.pack()

insertButton = Button(top_left_frame, text = "Insert Vertex")
insertButton.pack(side = LEFT)

delete_button = Button(top_left_frame, text = "Delete Vertex")
delete_button.pack(side = RIGHT)

insertButton = Button(top_left_frame, text = "MaxFlow", command = lambda:ford_fulkerson(graph, 'A', 'H', flow_debug))
insertButton.pack(side = RIGHT)


f = plt.Figure(figsize=(5, 5), dpi=100)
right_frame = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=window)
right_frame.get_tk_widget().pack(side=RIGHT, fill = BOTH, expand=1)
right_frame.draw()
toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(right_frame, window)
right_frame._tkcanvas.pack(side = RIGHT)
toolbar.update()

window.mainloop()
```

And also, the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm, to be safe:

```py
def ford_fulkerson(graph, source, sink, debug=None):
    flow, path = 0, True

    while path:
        # search for path with flow reserve
        path, reserve = depth_first_search(graph, source, sink)
        flow += reserve

        # increase flow along the path
        for v, u in zip(path, path[1:]):
            if graph.has_edge(v, u):
                graph[v][u]['flow'] += reserve
            else:
                graph[u][v]['flow'] -= reserve

        # show intermediate results
        if callable(debug):
            debug(graph, path, reserve, flow)


def depth_first_search(graph, source, sink):
    undirected = graph.to_undirected()
    explored = {source}
    stack = [(source, 0, dict(undirected[source]))]

    while stack:
        v, _, neighbours = stack[-1]
        if v == sink:
            break

        # search the next neighbour
        while neighbours:
            u, e = neighbours.popitem()
            if u not in explored:
                break
        else:
            stack.pop()
            continue

        # current flow and capacity
        in_direction = graph.has_edge(v, u)
        capacity = e['capacity']
        flow = e['flow']
        neighbours = dict(undirected[u])

        # increase or redirect flow at the edge
        if in_direction and flow < capacity:
            stack.append((u, capacity - flow, neighbours))
            explored.add(u)
        elif not in_direction and flow:
            stack.append((u, flow, neighbours))
            explored.add(u)

    # (source, sink) path and its flow reserve
    reserve = min((f for _, f, _ in stack[1:]), default=0)
    path = [v for v, _, _ in stack]

    return path, reserve
```

This is what I'm getting right now:
!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLQBV.jpg)
I want to switch from one stage to another by using these:
!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lf4Mj.jpg)

Comment: you could create many `Figures` and draw every stage on different `Figure` and late only `pack()` and `unpack()` correct figure - to show and hide it in window.

Comment: can I pack it directly to the NavigationToolbar?

Comment: if widget will have `toolbar` as parent widget (`Button(toolbar, ...)`) then it will displayed in `NavigationToolbar2Tk` - this way you can add buttons to toolbar.

Comment: maybe there is better method but you can assign function to button with left arrow `toolbar.children['!button2'].config(command=my_function)`, button with right arrow need `['!button3']`

Comment: Actually, I get an `AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'pack'` when trying to pack the figure

Comment: you already have one `Figure` in code and you should know how to add it to window  - you can't use `pack()` directly on figure. You have to use `FigureCanvasTkAgg`, etc.

Comment: I've figured out that only the text added on every edge stacks up on one another, so theoretically, I can store every edge text in a list and show the flow on different periods. The problem is that I can't figure out how to save the canvas at a specific time, save it and show it again using the toolbar buttons.
I've made some changes:
```
ax2 = f1.add_subplot(111)`
`texts = list()`
`texts.append(ax2.text(x, y, label, size=16, color=color, horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center'))

`

Comment: probably inside `ford_fulkerson` you would have to create canvas, draw one stage and keep canvas on some list, then create another canvas, draw next stage and  keep canvas on the same list, etc. If you will have list with many canvas then you can use button with arrow to display `canvas[0]` or `canvas[1]`, etc.